# Sort (sorting) order of files in notebook list

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

How can I change the sort order of files in the notebook list? I would like it to be alphabetical for all file types and not case sensitive. Directories can appear before files or within the files.

Currently my list is sorted as follows:
- Directories (starting with upper case)
- directories (starting with lower case)
- IPython notebooks (starting with upper case)
- ipython noteooks (starting with lower case)
- Other files (starting with upper case)
- other files (staring with lower case)

I'm using Jupyter 3.0.0-f75fda4

Comment: Good to know. I put in a issue/enhancement request at https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/184

Answer (score 3):

just as an addition to the previous post:

edit `..\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\notebook\static\tree\js\notebooklist.js` for instance to sort last modified first:

```
this.sort_function = modified_sorter(0); // inserted
this.sort_id = 'last-modified';          // inserted
this.sort_direction = 0;                 // inserted
//this.sort_function = name_sorter(1);
// 0 => descending, 1 => ascending
//this.sort_id = 'sort-name';
//this.sort_direction = 1;
```

You will have to make the same changes to `main.min.js` in the same directory. Naturally, with every update of jupyter notebook this will be lost. Also, no guarantees as this is a quick and dirty fix.

EDIT: in case you have already created a virtual env  make sure to do the same for ..\Anaconda\envs<venv>..

Comment: I followed the workaround here, added a `custom.js` and it works really well https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/184#issuecomment-632182058

Comment: Thanks @jerrytim. Using `custom.js` is nicer as it is kept between jupyter updates and can be more easily shared across computers.
Btw vote/work on this issue to have it implemented in jupyter: https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/1267

Answer (score 1):

If you are handy with jQuery, you can edit IPython's static files and customize the "tree" page you are referring to.

On my Ubuntu machine I could manipulate the page by editing the file `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/html/static/tree/js/notebooklist.js`